# How to extract Key or the first value of JSON parsed object

Tags: javascript, json

I have parsed an object into JSON. When I use the console log, it shows like this.

```
{14: "Cromwell"}
```

How can I get the key value from it.

Comment: is the object that you are trying to parse is dynamic?

Comment: I guess the problem is that John is trying to acces the object by using something like "myObject.14", which is forbidden by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop to split each key-value pair, like this:

```js
var data = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'};
for(var key in data){
  console.log('key = ' + key + ', value = ' + data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your variable is named "myObj", so you'll have:

```
const myObj = {14:"Cromwell"};
```

To access the key, you can use the Object.keys method:

```
const myKey = Object.keys(myObject).pop();
```

This will return you "14" as a result, which is a string equivalent of the key you're trying to obtain. To convert it to an integer, just use the parseInt() method.

To get the value from that object, then you can do:

```
const myValue = myObject[myKey];
```